# Transfer function of following system equation

Tags: control, transfer-function

Input to the system: U;
Output of the system: Y;
F is a disturbance;
s is the Laplace parameter

System equation:
sY = F - kY + U

To build the transfer function I need to bring the equation to the form G(s) = Y / U. Because of the additional summand F it is not possible to bring the equation into the above form.
Am I overseeing something or is it possible to bring it into the above form?

Comment: This is not the way you should study the problem. You have to study two different transfer functions : Y/U (with no disturbance) and Y/F (with no input). You can then add them together : Y = TF1*U + TF2*F.

Comment: (following): It makes indeed no sense to take into account disturbances when you are interested in the input/output signal relationship and vice versa

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
To find the steady-state error I would:
1) assume the disturbance F as constant
2) the input U as a step.
But is it correct to say then: lim s*Y(s) for s->0 is the steady state value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transfer function is a ratio of a single output to a single input whether the input is a disturbance or otherwise.

So to find the TF based on U, set F=0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do I find the steady-state error of this system (with disturbance). I have following steps in mind:
1) find transfer function
2) look at step response -> final value theorem -> impact of disturbance is visible
For the final value theorem I would have used the transfer-function.

Comment: You should post a new question. You get better answers that way.